# Error when transforming numpy array to PIL Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a variable `img` which is a `int64 numpy.array` with sizes 28x28. Its content looks like this:

```
[...]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  68 154 188 176 254 254 254 254 254
  227 106  17   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[...]
```

I want to convert the array to a PIL image. To do so I call `img = Image.fromarray(img, mode='L')` but the output I get is only 0s while it is obvious that it shouldn't be like that. I have checked the `mode` options and seems like L is correct. Also checked other answers inside stackoverflow and couldn't find something that reproduces this particular problem.

> L (8-bit pixels, black and white)

Why is this "simple" piece of code given an unexpected behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't the input be of dtype `np.uint8`?

Comment: You're correct! Thank you so much (it actually makes so much sense) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Divakar pointed out, the data types were not coherent.

Just by adding `np.uint8()` it works:

```
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img), mode='L')
```